# Use Firebug to get a deep copy of CSS in elements

Tags: css, firebug

I am using Firebug to inspect the elements of a webpage.  On the right hand of the page there is a "style" tab that list all the CSS styling for a given tag.  These CSS styling are coming from a linked CSS page.

What I am looking to do is somehow copy a set of divs with the CSS hardcoded in the div.  This way I can copy and paste the elements and have the exact same styling.  Is this possible to do with Firebug or perhaps another tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Firebug, but you could build a script to do it.

List the CSS you want to copy (every property you believe is required to make it portable) and then loop through in JS and `getComputedStyle()`. Then build a `;` delimited list of `property:value` pairs, and assign it to the `style` attribute if your element and all children.

This doesn't look like an easy task - and you will no doubt run into problems.

Answer (score 7):

I used IE9 to accomplish this.

1. Open a page where you want to grab a style in IE9
2. Press F12 to display Developer Toolbar
3. In the Developer Toolbar press Find and select "Select element by click"
4. Then go to "View" > "Source" and select "Element source with style"

Comment: Feature is also available in IE8 to.

Comment: not available in IE11. Btw I use chrome to copy paste the css of an elment and then clean it up, I fear there is no way to copy paste css without descriptions which mess up css in chrome?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do here but are you trying to apply the same style to multiple elements (divs)? If so you should use a css class. So your html will be

```
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

and css will be

```
.myClass
{
height:whatever;
width:whatever;
etc
}
```