# FireBug (or any other method) - How to copy all CSS styling from DIV and child divs?

Tags: css, firebug, children, deep-copy

I am trying to copy all the css styling from a div (and all child/inner divs).
I mostly user FireBug and am hoping there is a simple way to do this so I don't have to go through thousands of lines of the CSS stylesheet to pick out the handful I need.

Does anyone know how to do this with FireBug? Or any other developer tool? (i.e Chrome, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

As per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8013320/900747 you can use IE9 or IE8:

1. Open a page where you want to grab a style in IE9
2. Press F12 to display Developer Toolbar
3. In the Developer Toolbar press Find and select "Select element by click"
4. Then go to "View" > "Source" and select "Element source with style"

This should also give all parent styles to ensure the layout is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you select the pointer button in Firebug you can select the element.

[image]

Then you can select the element on the page or from within the HTML element, and then you can see the CSS to the right of Firebug. You can then copy by highlighting the CSS and hitting ctrl + c.

Comment: You can do this in IE 9 above, Chrome by hitting F12.